# Why does passing a large dictionary from python to julia flatten contained multidimensional lists?

Tags: javascript, python, json, julia, code-translation

Okay so...I'm in the process of creating a python client for a coding game I play. This game is originally created in javascript and employs a json object of game data found at https://adventure.land/data.js. Within this data, each map has a list of doors, and each door within this list is a list of attributes. For example:

```
"doors":[[-965,-176,24,30,"woffice",0,1],[536,1665,64,32,"tunnel",0,2],[168,-149,32,40,"bank",0,3],[160,1370,24,32,"cave",0,4],[232,384,24,30,"arena",0,6],[-472,131,24,30,"tavern",0,8],[616,610,32,40,"mansion",0,10],[1936,-23,24,24,"level1",1,11],[169,-404,24,40,"hut",0,14],[1600,-547,60,40,"halloween",4,15],[312,-335,32,32,"mtunnel",0,16],[967,-584,32,32,"mtunnel",1,17],[1472,-434,32,32,"mtunnel",2,18]]
```

However, when sent from python to julia, it suddenly becomes:

```
"doors":[-965,-176,24,30,"woffice",0,1,536,1665,64,32,"tunnel",0,2,168,-149,32,40,"bank",0,3,160,1370,24,32,"cave",0,4,232,384,24,30,"arena",0,6,-472,131,24,30,"tavern",0,8,616,610,32,40,"mansion",0,10,1936,-23,24,24,"level1",1,11,169,-404,24,40,"hut",0,14,1600,-547,60,40,"halloween",4,15,312,-335,32,32,"mtunnel",0,16,967,-584,32,32,"mtunnel",1,17,1472,-434,32,32,"mtunnel",2,18]
```

Is there some way to prevent this from happening? If not, is there a possible workaround? Because my `for door in doors` code in python won't exactly have the same effect when given a direct translation to julia considering the random list flattening.

Edit: I've been asked to provide "minimum reproducible code" but I'm not too sure what the minimum is so I'll just say...

1. create a some function in julia that prints a dictionary

```
function printDict(d)
    println(d)
end
```

2. create a dictionary in python that contains a nested list

```
nestedlistdict = {"data": [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]}
```

3. call the `printDict` function from python while sending the `nestedlistdict` variable as an argument

```
from julia import Main
Main.include("path/to/your/julia/file")
Main.file.printDict(nestedlistdict)
```

4. result *should* be:
   `Dict{Any, Any}("data" => [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]])`but instead my result is `Dict{Any, Any}("data" => [0 1 2 3; 4 5 6 7])`

Edit2: upon further testing, it seems to be having the issue because it converts a nested list into a `Matrix` object instead of a nested `Vector` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia uses the same interpretation of list of lists as numpy:

```
>>> np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

or in Julia:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> py"[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

If you want to have an actual vector of vectors you need to do the same way as you need to do a vector of numpy arrays.
Python version:

```
>>> [np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2,3])]
[np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]
```

Julia version (this is what you are actually asking for):

```
julia> np = pyimport("numpy");

julia> py"[$np.array([1, 2, 3]), $np.array([1, 2, 3])]"
2-element Vector{Vector{Int32}}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 3]
```

Another, perhaps simpler option could be packing that all to a tuple:

```
julia> py"tuple([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])"
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do without numpy due to the overhead of installing it within my package. I did find one workaround where I can simply test if the type is a matrix and then convert it back into a vector of vectors; though this seems to have a lot of overhead as well.

Comment: what about a tuple (see my last edit)?

Comment: While that would work in principle, I'm not sure how to implement it. I have to use almost the entirety of the `data.js` file linked above within my client; and the issue happens upon transferring the data in that file from python to julia. Unfortunately, these solutions seem to all be more of a "repair the problem" rather than a "prevent the problem" if that makes sense.

Comment: I have found another workaround where I simply send the entire grouping of data as a string and then have Julia parse it as JSON because for whatever reason, converting from JSON to Julia doesn't change nested lists into matrices.; so far it may be my best option.

Comment: figured out how to modify the json file so that instead of a 'list of lists' it contains a 'tuple of lists' like you suggested; so now I just have to make that work and hopefully I won't have any other major issues. lol tysm